# At what scale is Quantum Mechanics start to influence body's behaviour?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics

What is the biggest body that shows quantum behaviour? An atom? All of them or are there ones that don't act in a quantum manner because of their size?

Comment: This strikes me as an ill-defined question: What constitutes "quantum behavior"? For one, most physicists believe that *everything* is governed by quantum mechanics, and classical mechanics is often merely a very good approximation. For another, the fusion processes in the sun are quantum mechanical in nature. Does that mean the sun "shows quantum behaviour"?

Comment: Yeah, the question is very vague, yet I didn't specify. I mean, when do the wave equation and indefinition of particles' characteristics become *relevant*? At which scale? (I suppose relevant when the error of not using it becomes > 0.001).

Comment: At the distance scale of the limits of the observable universe: the CMB is a consequence of quantum mechanics and its signal came here through the electromagnetic quantum field. Astronomers are experiencing the CMB by seeing it with their eyes, which are absorbing the quanta (photons) from their computer screens showing the CMB. They are changing their behavior based on that visual information. I do agree with @ACuriousMind, though, that the question has nothing to do with physics. Absolutely everything in this universe is quantum mechanical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is not currently feasible to test objects of arbitrarily large size in (for example) a double slit experiment, the larger and larger we get we still see quantum mechanical effects. It seems unlikely (and, in my and many physicists' view unphysical) for there to ever be a cutoff where those effects just stop happening completely. If physicists say large objects don't behave quantum mechanically, what they really mean is generally that we just don't need to treat them with quantum mechanics because the effects are too small to notice anyway.